# Distinguishing between 0 and null in OR statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have below code in my function, I want to assign a value to the variable newValue.

`var newValue = fieldValue || originalValue || masterValue;`

Here if I have the originalValue = 0, the java script treats it as false/null and assigns masterValue to the newValue.
Instead I want to assign originalValue (0) to the newValue.

Is there a way to achieve this without an extra line of code?

Comment: You want to check specifically for `null` then, and not just any falsy value?

Comment: Actually for null and false both, just don't want to check for 0.

Comment: Then no, there is no way to do that without additional code, wether you put that code on the same line or not, would be up to you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate of the `==` vs `===` questions.

Comment: Ya, good call.  my bad

Comment: @ssube Not at all, the `||` operator has nothing to do with equality

Comment: @Bergi but "distinguishing between 0 and null" has everything to do with equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but it gets a bit complicated (*using the ternary operator*).

```
var newValue = fieldValue || (originalValue || originalValue===0) ? originalValue : masterValue;
```

(*this assumes you want to 0 to be assigned even when in `fieldValue`*)

Comment: Now try doing `false || false==0` and see what you get *(hint: you need strict comparison)*?

Comment: Actually no, only in the originalValue.

Comment: @Y.Solanki updated (*for only the `originalValue` and fix for @adenao comment*)

Comment: Yup, non strict comparison would tell you that `false` and `0` is the same thing, it's the same issue `||` has.

Answer (score 1):

Define a "good" value with a predicate and pass it to [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function:

```
var isValid = x => !!x || x === 0;
var newValue = [fieldValue, originalValue, masterValue].find(isValid);
```

If you target old MSIEs, `.find` can be replaced with `.filter(...)[0]`.

```js
var isValid = x => !!x || x === 0;

console.log([1, 2, 3].find(isValid));
console.log([false, 0, 3].find(isValid));
console.log([null, 0, 3].find(isValid));
console.log([undefined, 0, 3].find(isValid));
console.log(["", 0, false].find(isValid));
console.log(["", null, false].find(isValid));
```

Comment: nice, although to a comment the OP mentions that the 0 should be valid only for the `originalValue` variable, not any of them.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use

```
var newValue = fieldValue;
if (newValue == null)
    newVAlue = originalValue;
if (newValue == null)
    newValue = masterValue;
```

The `||` operator is pretty sloppy and should not be used when you need to deal with falsy values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get this working with one line of code here is an option:

```
var fieldValue = false;
var originalValue = 0;
var masterValue = 5;

var newValue = fieldValue || (originalValue===0)?0:originalValue || masterValue;

console.log(newValue); // newValue=0
```